# <input type=button value="Previous Page" onClick="history.go(-1)"> Warning: Page has Expired IE

Tags: javascript

I am trying to send user to previous page history.go(-1). This works fine in Firefox but fails in IE
ERROR:
Warning: Page has Expired The page you requested was created using information you submitted in a form. This page is no longer available. As a security precaution, Internet Explorer does not automatically resubmit your information for you.

To resubmit your information and view this Web page, click the Refresh button.

Anyone came across this issue. Please help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Firebug to see what headers are being set in response to the form post.  I bet it's the `cache-control` header that is the culprit.

[Reference](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/183763)

Answer (score 2):

This generally means that on the previous page there was some sort of POST, to fix this remove the POST on the previous page by using session variables or another method to wait to submit the data until all forms are completed.

If this does not sufficiently answer your question, please provide more detail (e.g. using PHP, submitting data on the previous page) and/or code examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start(); 
session_destroy();
?>
```

Use Session destroy in the page where your form resides at the very top of the code...This is a fix for IE and any other browser.

Answer (score -1):

I came across such an issue.  Actually `history.go` can used for (-1),(-2).So if the page is refreshed more than two times and then back button is used, it wont allow it to use the same.
For it,one should call javascript method `onclick="getURL()"`

In this `getURL()`,it is required to pass the link of the page required.