# How to back to search result after exit the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How can i back to the search result after i click to any page on the website i have a search page after submit and have the result the user can click on any other page or maybe to view more details for a product how can i return back to the same result that he did the search on it

i tired this but it didn't give me a result

```
<a href="javascript:history.back(-1);">Previous Page</a>

<button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>

<script>
function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
}
</script>
```

and this give me this error message on the browser

**Confirm form resubmission
This webpage requires data that you entered earlier in order to be properly displayed. You can send this data again, but by doing so you will repeat any action this page previously performed. Press Reload to resend that data and display this page.
Press the reload button to resubmit the data needed to load the page.**

and i tried this

```
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['http_referrer']; ?>">Search Result</a>
```

all this didn' give me the result i want

How can i solve this problem ???!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent browser waring when you hit the 'go back' button after form submit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687083/prevent-browser-waring-when-you-hit-the-go-back-button-after-form-submit)

Comment: Why not passing the URL of the previous page to the "search results" page and instead of "window.history.back()" have a "window.location.href = previousUrl" (where previousUrl is a variable that hold the mentioned above URL)

Comment: <a  onClick="history.go(-1)">Go back</a>    try this .....

Comment: @AmanKumar it give me this when i click on it Document Expired

This document is no longer available.

The requested document is not available in Firefox’s cache.

    As a security precaution, Firefox does not automatically re-request sensitive documents.
    Click Try Again to re-request the document from the website.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651300/input-type-button-value-previous-page-onclick-history-go-1-warning-page

Comment: @AmanKumar i don't understand what should i do